# Can you prevent users from checking out revisions other than the latest one in subversion?

Tags: svn

Can A, who is the admin on a repo, deny B access to revisions older than the latest one? If it helps, B does not commit/make changes to the repo. All B needs to be able to do is checkout the latest revision.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Ether For instance, because you know that there have been mistakes made in the past of committing relatively confidential files to the SVN, and that although they have been cleaned up by now, the person you are granting access to could find them in the history.

Comment: I think in that case you should look at obliterating the sensitive revision(s) from the repository. (see 'svn obliterate`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not... but you could take away B's access to the SVN repository, and then set up a proxy of some sort (e.g. a CGI script triggered by a web page) that would do an 'svn export', zip it up, and present the zip file to B for download.  Then give B access to the proxy only.